# Copy Column and Paste in the same worksheet a variable number of times

Tags: vba, excel

I am going mad trying to do the simplest thing in VBA.

I want to automate the copying of Column C on a worksheet a variable number of times to the adjacent columns D, E, F...etc. of the same worksheet.

Stepping through the code, I have it copying the correct column ("C:C") but cannot get it to paste via Paste, Offset or Destination to column D etc. for the variable number of instances.

this is the code I'm using.  Assume all the Dim and Set statements are done as it's a small part of larger Sub.

```
    sht02AnalysisSummary.Activate

    For i = 0 To AddCol
        i = i + 1
        lLastCol = sht02AnalysisSummary.Range("C3").End(xlToLeft).Column
        rangeCopy.Copy
        Column.Offset("0,lLastCol+i").Paste
    Next i

    sht01CoverPage.Activate
```

This sort of works now but with AddCol set at 3, the result is skipping Column D and only repeating the pasting once (into Column E) whereas it should be pasting into D,E & F.  Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jeeped.  I was actually too embarrassed to show my code because it was a mangled mess that I couldn't make head nor tail of myself.  It has now been posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not manually code your iteration var in a For ... Next; you will be disrupting the built-in iteration and progression.
2. The `xlToLeft` leaves me confused about the destination (or is it source...?). Perhaps that should be `xlToRight` or your should start further right before starting to look to the left ?
3. you should be able to paste a single column into three consecutive destination columns at once.

   ```
   AddCol = 3
   with sht02AnalysisSummary
       set rangeCopy = .range(.cells(3, "C"), .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup))
       rangeCopy.Copy destination:=.Cells(3, .columns.count).End(xlToLeft).resize(rangeCopy.rows.count, AddCol)
   end with
   ```

Comment: 1.Thanks Jeeped, I didn't know that For...Next can disrupt built-in iteration and progression.  When I repeat the code elsewhere in the workbook, I'll keep that in mind.  2.  I was using xLToLeft to find the last empty column after Column C once the process began.  Your code will negate its use.  3.  Thanks for the code sample, I will paste it into the Sub and let you know hat happens.  Thanks again.

Comment: Without `i = i + 1` the For ... Next iterates `i` as 0, 1, 2, 3. With it, `i` is used as 1, 3 only. If you need to jump by 2 (e.g. 1, 3) then use `For i = 1 To AddCol Step 2`.

Comment: Hi Jeeped.  Will using Excel 2010 make any difference to the code as the whole line is being highlighted and an Error 1004 is coming up?  I will add that rangeCopy = sht02AnalysisSummary.Range("C:C") and my original code referred to cell C3 because there is nothing in Cells C1 & C2.  If that helps

Comment: I've adjust for the correct source of the copy above. However, you might just want to fill right rather than copy.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, that certainly adds columns.  I will need to find a way to stop it from overwriting Column C which it's doing at the moment.  Also, it's not copying the formatting of the whole of Column C (Cells C1 & C2 and the Column width are not being copied). I'll look up FillRight up as I've not used it before.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With sht
    .Columns(3).Copy .Columns(4)
End With
End Sub
```